# Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement in fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The code is here:

```
interface
    subroutine csrcoo (nrow,job,nzmax,a,ja,ia,nnz,ao,ir,jc,ierr) bind(c,name="CSRCOO")
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    integer(c_int), value :: nrow,job,nzmax,nnz
    real(c_double) :: a(*),ao(*)
    integer(c_int) :: ir(*),jc(*),ja(*),ia(nrow+1),ierr
    end subroutine csrcoo
end interface

subroutine csrcoo (nrow,job,nzmax,a,ja,ia,nnz,ao,ir,jc,ierr)
    integer :: nrow,job,nzmax,nnz
    real*8 :: a(*),ao(*)
    integer :: ir(*),jc(*),ja(*),ia(nrow+1),ierr

    integer :: i,k,k1,k2
    ierr = 0
    nnz = ia(nrow+1)-1

    if (nnz > nzmax) then
        ierr = 1
        return
    endif

    goto (3,2,1) job
    1 do 10 k=1,nnz
        ao(k) = a(k)
    10 END DO
    2 do 11 k=1,nnz
        jc(k) = ja(k)
    11 END DO

    3 do 13 i=nrow,1,-1
        k1 = ia(i+1)-1
        k2 = ia(i)
        do 12 k=k1,k2,-1
            ir(k) = i
        12 END DO
    13 END DO
    return
end subroutine csrcoo
```

When I use the gfortran to compile this code like this: `gfortran -O2 -c test.f90`
It always shows this error:

```
test.f90:11:

subroutine csrcoo (nrow,job,nzmax,a,ja,ia,nnz,ao,ir,jc,ierr)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
test.f90:41.3:

end subroutine csrcoo
   1
Error: Expecting END PROGRAM statement at (1)
Error: Unexpected end of file in 'test.f90'
```

Can anyone tell me what wrong with that code and give me some advice?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that a standalone interface doesn't make any sense, because its name has to be accessible inside the part of the program, where you want to use it. Therefore, it has to be defined inside a `module` or a `program`.

I think, the error stems from the fact, that the `program` statement is not necessary and your interface, therefor, implicitely defines a program, which should be ended with an `end` statement, which is obviously missing.

You can solve your problem by wrapping your interface in a module and leaving the subroutine out of the module (otherwise, your subroutine would already have a module interface).

```
module [name]
    [your interface]
end module

[your subroutine]
```

**EDIT** (Suggestion form @HighPerformanceMark): The better solution for the code you showed us would be to put the subroutine itself into the module and delete the interface. In this case, the interface for the subroutine is created automatically and you don't have to care for it.

```
module [name]
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none

    subroutine csrcoo (nrow,job,nzmax,a,ja,ia,nnz,ao,ir,jc,ierr) bind(c,name="CSRCOO")
        [the content of your subroutine]
    end subroutine
end module
```

Comment: Better, surely, to advise OP to put the subroutine in the module and drop the separate specification of its interface ?  Unless, that is, OP uses the same interface for multiple routines but there is little sign of that in the question.